# WHERE condition with a CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Referring to the sections in bold, basically having product codes and adding the eligible age for the product in the case statement. So below we have products where age is either 18 or 14 to use product. Created a new column as 'Eligibility'

Now referring to the second bold section, i only want accounts where the 'Eligibility'>'AgeAtOpenDate ie the account holder is too young for the account.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN EOMONTH(OpenDate,0) = a.[EtlFileDate] THEN 'New Account'
        ELSE 'Existing Account'
        END AS 'NewAccountsInMonth'
    ,CASE
        **WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (801,802) THEN '18'
        WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490) THEN '14'
        END as 'Eligibility'**
    ,a.[EtlFileDate]
    ,a.[AccountNumber]
    ,a.[OpenDate] 
    ,a.[ProductCode]
    ,a.[ProductName]  
    ,a.[PrimaryCAN]
    ,b.[Cust_Age]
    ,b.[Cust_BirthDate]
    ,**(DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] ) as 'AgeAtOpenDate'**
FROM Histaccounts a
join Marketable b
    on a.[PrimaryCAN]=b.[CAN]
**where 'Eligibility'>'AgeAtOpenDate'**
    and a.[EtlFileDate] between '2021-10-31' and '2023-03-23' 
    and a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490,802,801)
```

When I run the above script im still getting all the results rather than the ones that are under age.

What am I doing wrong? Does it have to do with the fact that you cant use a WHERE condition that is based on a CASE in the SELECT area?

Comment: You cannot reference a column by its alias in the `WHERE`. You would need to repeat the expression (bad idea here), use a CTE/derived table, or use explicit `AND`/`OR` logic.

Comment: Also, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Also, outside of rare cases, `DATEDIFF(year, <DOB>, <LaterDate>)` doesn't compute what most humans would declare someone's age at `LaterDate` to be. `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions* of the given `datepart`. So unless you consider someone born on `2022-12-31` to be age 1 on `2023-01-01`, you need to correct that too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot use an alias in the **WHERE** clause that is defined in the **SELECT** statement. The WHERE clause is evaluated before the **SELECT** statement, so the alias `Eligibility` and `AgeAtOpenDate` are not recognized in the **WHERE** clause.

You can rewrite your query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN EOMONTH(OpenDate,0) = a.[EtlFileDate] THEN 'New Account'
            ELSE 'Existing Account'
        END AS 'NewAccountsInMonth',
        CASE
            WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (801,802) THEN '18'
            WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490) THEN '14'
        END as 'Eligibility',
        a.[EtlFileDate],
        a.[AccountNumber],
        a.[OpenDate],
        a.[ProductCode],
        a.[ProductName],
        a.[PrimaryCAN],
        b.[Cust_Age],
        b.[Cust_BirthDate],
        DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] ) as 'AgeAtOpenDate'
    FROM Histaccounts a
    JOIN Marketable b
    ON a.[PrimaryCAN]=b.[CAN]
    WHERE a.[EtlFileDate] BETWEEN '2021-10-31' AND '2023-03-23' 
        AND a.[ProductCode] IN (480,481,489,490,802,801)
) subquery
WHERE subquery.Eligibility > subquery.AgeAtOpenDate
```

Comment: Sort of. Whether you can or can't use the alias, the WHERE clause will see the original code as string literals rather than an attempt to use an alias at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace in where clause with the whole logic

```
where (CASE WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (801,802) THEN '18'
WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490) THEN '14'
END > (DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] > (DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] )) > (DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] )) and a.[EtlFileDate] between '2021-10-31' and '2023-03-23' and a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490,802,801)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can insert records in temp table and then apply filter

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EOMONTH(OpenDate,0) = a.[EtlFileDate] THEN 'New Account'
ELSE 'Existing Account'
END AS 'NewAccountsInMonth'
,CASE WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (801,802) THEN '18'
WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490) THEN '14'
END as 'Eligibility'
,a.[EtlFileDate]
,a.[AccountNumber]
,a.[OpenDate] 
,a.[ProductCode]
,a.[ProductName]  
,a.[PrimaryCAN]
,b.[Cust_Age]
,b.[Cust_BirthDate]
,(DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] ) as [AgeAtOpenDate]
into #Test
FROM Histaccounts a
join Marketable b
on a.[PrimaryCAN]=b.[CAN]
WHERE a.[EtlFileDate] between '2021-10-31' and '2023-03-23' and a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490,802,801)

SELECT * from #Test
WHERE Eligibility>AgeAtOpenDate
```

CTE

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EOMONTH(OpenDate,0) = a.[EtlFileDate] THEN 'New Account'
ELSE 'Existing Account'
END AS 'NewAccountsInMonth'
,CASE WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (801,802) THEN '18'
WHEN a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490) THEN '14'
END as 'Eligibility'
,a.[EtlFileDate]
,a.[AccountNumber]
,a.[OpenDate] 
,a.[ProductCode]
,a.[ProductName]  
,a.[PrimaryCAN]
,b.[Cust_Age]
,b.[Cust_BirthDate]
,(DATEDIFF(year,b.[Cust_BirthDate],a.[OpenDate] ) as [AgeAtOpenDate]
into #Test
FROM Histaccounts a
join Marketable b
on a.[PrimaryCAN]=b.[CAN]
WHERE a.[EtlFileDate] between '2021-10-31' and '2023-03-23' and a.[ProductCode] in (480,481,489,490,802,801)
)
SELECT * from CTE
WHERE Eligibility>AgeAtOpenDate
```

Comment: Adding temp tables is rarely the best option.

Comment: That's why I added the `cte` code which resolves OP's query, I suspect best option here is to create a `view` instead `cte`

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues here, but the biggest is the values `'Eligibility'` and `'AgeAtOpenDate'` in the `WHERE` clause are interpreted as string literals, rather than references to the column aliases, and since `E` is greater than `A` the condition always succeeds.

You can fix this in several ways, but in this instance you're probably best off repeating the `CASE` expressions. Do it *exactly*, and SQL Server is smart enough to know the expressions in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses are the same and will only compute them once. Any kind of nesting or layering, and there's a chance you lose the use of indexes that might help the query.